# adb can find device but fastboot cannot

Tags: rooting, nexus-4, fastboot, 4.3-jelly-bean

### Context

I can run adb commands on my Nexus 4 and they work fine but when my device is in the bootloader and I try to list the device with,

```
fastboot devices
```

my device is not listed. I was having problems with adb on my Windows 7 VM due to driver issues, so I switched to OSX because it does not require any drivers.

I think I may have corrupted my bootloader and recovery in my previous attempts to root my phone with a toolkit(I know I should have done it manually).

### Question

Is it possible to reinstall my bootloader or a recovery using just adb i.e. without using fastboot?

Comment: That might be possible if you find some images to load via the revocery's *install update.zip from sdcard* feature (just as a hint what you might want to look out for; I don't have a Nexus, so I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: My recovery was corrupted too, I couldn't reach it. Anyway, the problem resolved itself. I didn't do anything different other than add the `adb` and `fastboot` commands to my bin folder.

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer (so others can see there's a solution), and accept it lateron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my device not showing up with the `fastboot devices` command resolved itself. I was then able to flash a custom recovery.

The only thing I did different was, I rebooted my computer and symlinked the `adb` and `fastboot` commands in my bin folder.